# How to inject dependency using koin in top level function

Tags: kotlin, koin

I have top-level function like

```
fun sendNotification(context:Context, data:Data) {
    ...//a lot of code here
}
```

That function creates notifications, sometimes notification can contain image, so I have to download it. I`m using Glide which is wrapped over interface ImageManager, so I have to inject it. I use Koin for DI and the problem is that I cannot write

```
val imageManager: ImageManager by inject()
```

somewhere in my code, because there is no something that implements KoinComponent interface.

The most obvious solution is to pass already injected somewhere else `imageManager` as parameter of function but I dont want to do it, because in most cases I dont need `imageManager`: it depends on type of `Data` parameter.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Easiest way is to create `KoinComponent` object as wrapper and then to get variable from it:

```
val imageManager = object:KoinComponent {val im: ImageManager by inject()}.im
```

Btw its better to wrap it by some function, for example I use

```
inline fun <reified T> getKoinInstance(): T {
    return object : KoinComponent {
        val value: T by inject()
    }.value
}
```

So if I need instance I just write

```
val imageManager:ImageManager = getKoinInstance()
```

or

```
val imageManager = getKoinInstance<ImageManager>()
```

Comment: the solution in the first snippet worked but the inline function does not (for me). I had to change it `<reified T : Any>`

Answer (score 4):

I did it in this way

```kotlin
fun Route.general() {

val repo: OperationRepo by lazy { GlobalContext.get().koin.get() }
...
}
```